# How do I restart redis that I installed with brew?

Tags: macos, reboot, homebrew

I used brew to install redis (a key/value store database server) for my node.js app.

```
brew install redis
```

However, it seems to disappear and is very volatile. Because I'm using redis as my session store, I need to be able to quickly restart it on my mac when this happens.

How do I restart redis that I installed with brew?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found all these options listed in brew package (`brew info redis`) to be very buggy. For example redis throws a bunch of errors if it isn't started with root. I ended up just doing the direct call with sudo and removing launchctl files.

```
sudo redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

I was hoping there was a way to easily restart redis from the command line, but that doesn't seem possible. Therefore, I run with daemon mode set to 'no' and watch it log to stdout, then I can kill it easily.

Comment: I've appended this command with '& disown' to background and detach from the process

Comment: See the other answer that uses `launchctl`, it works and is supported now by the brew recipe.

Answer (score 74):

**update**

brew services expired due to no one want to maintain it. check below:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/28657

check `launchctl` function instead.

or `lunchy`

So instead of:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/io.redis.redis-server.plist
```

you can do this:

```
lunchy start redis
```

and:

```
lunchy ls
```

references: https://github.com/eddiezane/lunchy

It used to be able to use as below:

```
brew services restart redis
```

should be the restart command You want. You can also run

```
brew services list
```

which will give you list of your brew services.

Comment: I had to re-install redis with brew to get it in the startup plist, then this worked fine

Comment: "Warning: brew services is unsupported and will be removed soon."

Comment: It's pretty dumb to remove such useful shortcut. But it's buggy by the way. I can stop redis with `brew services`, but after that I'm unable to start it again.

Comment: brew doesn't support the "services" verb anymore as of 0.9.5

Comment: Use the answer below using `launchctl`, now that brew doesn't support "services" anymore

Comment: Please note that brew **does** support the the services command now via a tap. See the answer below, it is a more relevant answer now.

Answer (score 48):

As of Dec-7-2015 You can use `brew services`.

You need to `brew tap homebrew/services` and then thw following will work as expected:

**install** `brew install redis`

**start** `brew services start redis`

**stop** `brew services stop redis`

**restart** `brew services restart redis`

More info here:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services

Comment: conflicting answer above says `brew services` is deprecated.

Comment: @chovy They were deprecated because of lack of maintenance, but are now back again as a **brew tap**.  As you can see last commit is from _27 days ago_.

Comment: This is a more relevant and up to date answer now than the above ones, and faster to implement than going manual `launchctl` way.

Comment: It's 2017 and I'm using Brew v1.3.6 and this works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 23):

Brew doesn't support the `services` command anymore.

The recommended way is to use os x's `launchctl` command.

First you need to setup redis as a service managed by launchctl:

```
$ ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/redis/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Then you can use `launchctl load`/ `launchctl unload` to start/stop the service:

```
$ # start redis server
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
$
$ # stop redis server
$ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
```

Comment: brew 0.9.5 support services, here they are  
$ brew --version
Homebrew 0.9.5 (git revision bf22; last commit 2016-03-06)
$ brew services list
Name       Status  User Plist
postgresql stopped      
redis      stopped      
$

Answer (score 1):

For Homebrew 1.5.14

`redis-server`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates information present in [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1010357/461558)- can you differentiate it at all? :)

Comment: Now it's the same as [the accepted answer](//superuser.com/a/504957)!! (You really should just delete this answer.)

Comment: no it's not. He included the path to a conf file. Clearly not the same, and not required. I know I don't want to type the path to a conf file every time I start and stop Redis and I think anyone else reading this(besides you) would find that valuable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are successfully running `brew services start redis` or `brew services restart redis`, then seeing "Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused" when attempting to run `redis-cli`, you should verify the existence of your redis configuration file.

You can run `touch /usr/local/etc/redis.conf` or similar to create an empty configuration file.

Then run `brew services restart redis` and `redis-cli`, then voila!

```
127.0.0.1:6379> PING
PONG
```